# How to set width for PdfPTable and align table center in page

Tags: c#, itext, pdfptable

i'm starter in iTextSharp, i write this code for create RoundRectangle into  PdfPTable and align table in page center

```
 string pdfpath = Server.MapPath("PDFs");
        RoundRectangle rr = new RoundRectangle();

        using (Document document = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfpath + "/Graphics6.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew));
            document.Open();
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
                           float[] f=new float[]{0.5f};

            table.SetWidths(f);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell()
            {
                CellEvent = rr,
                Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER,

                Phrase = new Phrase("test")
            };
            table.AddCell(cell);
            document.Add(table);
```

i want change table width i change code

```
 string pdfpath = Server.MapPath("PDFs");
        RoundRectangle rr = new RoundRectangle();

        using (Document document = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfpath + "/Graphics6.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew));
            document.Open();
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            table.TotalWidth = 5;

            int[] w = new int[] { 12};
           table.SetWidths(w);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell()
            {
                CellEvent = rr,
                Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER,

                Phrase = new Phrase("test")
            };
            table.AddCell(cell);
            document.Add(table);
```

but no work and no change width table in page. please help me. thanks all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `TotalWidth` property for set width for `PdfPTable` like this code:

```
string pdfpath = Server.MapPath("PDFs");
RoundRectangle rr = new RoundRectangle();

using (Document document = new Document())
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfpath + "/Graphics200.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew));
    document.Open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.TotalWidth = 144f;

    table.LockedWidth = true;
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell()
    {
        CellEvent = rr,
        Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER,
        Phrase = new Phrase("test")
    };
    table.AddCell(cell);
    document.Add(table);
}
```